# getUserMedia() : get environment camera with wide enough field of view

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia, mediastream

I'm using rear smartphone camera using:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: "environment" }, audio: false })
   .then((stream) => {...})
```

However, when using those constraints on a Huawei P30 (having **3 rear camera sensors**),
the retrieved video stream has a very narrow field of view ; maybe the "zoom" sensor is used to retrieve the stream. For my app, I need a more "all purpose" field of view, not too narrow like that.

I found that I can get the stream from another sensor by using the constraint `deviceId` (value found using `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`), but I have to support as many smartphones as possible, so relying only on `deviceId` does not seems a viable option ([`deviceId` even changes for each origin & browsing session](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints/deviceId)).

Does any `getUserMedia()` constraint exists, allowing to get a camera stream with specific field of view angle (or any related characteristic such as focal length, zoom level...)?

Comment: Interesting resource: https://www.oberhofer.co/mediastreamtrack-and-its-capabilities/

Comment: Discussed on Reddit too https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/8eg8w5/choosing_cameras_in_javascript_with_the/ (solution looks wacky)